# Why Byobu custom status notification code fail to show in color?

Tags: server, bash, byobu, scripts

The code below runs well in Bash and shows text with proper green background color but when I add it to the `~/.byobu/bin/` folder it shows the escape characters instead. Something like **[42m[1mAAPL:30.345 (B[m**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo `tput setab 2;tput bold`AAPL:`curl -s 'http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv' | cut -d, -f2;tput sgr0`
```

Answer (score 7):

If using the `tmux` backend for byobu, you will need to use a different format for color codes. Luckily, it's less complicated than the `screen` format.

To set colors, use `#[<color and attribute codes>]`. Examples:

- `#[default]`: restore default colors (use at the end of your custom status).
- `#[fg=red]`: set the foreground color to red.
- `#[fg=#ff0000]`: set the foreground color to `#ff0000`. Only accepts lowercase -- `FF0000` won't work.
- `#[bg=black]`: makes the background black.
- `#[fg=bold]`: makes text **bold**. See below for more.
- `#[reverse]`: swaps foreground/background colors.

You can combine them, e.g. `#[fg=white,bold,bg=black]`.

Named colors: `black`, `red`, `green`, `yellow`, `blue`, `magenta`, `cyan`, `white`, `black`, `brightblack`, `brightred`, `brightgreen`, `brightyellow`, `brightblue`, `brightmagenta`, `brightcyan`, `brightwhite`

Attributes: `dim`, `underscore`, `bold`, `reverse`, `standout`, `blinking`, `hidden`, `italics`

You can also use the environment variables `$BYOBU_LIGHT`, `$BYOBU_DARK`, `$BYOBU_ACCENT`, and `$BYOBU_HIGHLIGHT` as colors.

---

To play with this, create a file, `~/.byobu/bin/1_hello` with the following contents, and make it executable.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "#[reverse]Hello world#[default]"
```

This should create a black-on-white status notification that says "Hello world".

---

[image: A few custom status notifications for byobu]

Here are two example custom status bar components, and the codes that produce them:

- `#[fg=#aa77cc,bg=#222222] @XXX.XX #[default]`
- `#[fg=white,bg=black] ✉ ️X #[default]`

This information will *probably* only work if you're using `tmux` and a color-enabled shell, though :)

---

(Sources: `/usr/lib/byobu/include/colors`, `/usr/lib/byobu/include/shutil`)

Answer (score 1):

You need other color specifiers in screen (see [Manpage of screen(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen)).
So first you should save the value in a variable:

```
AAPL=$(curl -s 'http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&=.csv' | cut -d, -f2)
```

And in the second step you can output it with `printf`:

```
printf "\005{= b}%s%s\005{-}" "AAPL: " "$AAPL"
```

Comment: ...I'm having precisely the same issue with the tmux backend